# Оживлена и оживлённа - каково различие по смыслу и по какому правилу пишется Н и НН?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, значение-слов, прилагательные

Соня действительно этот вечер была весела, оживлена и хороша, какой никогда еще не видал ее Николай. - Лев Толстой, Война и мир.

Княгиня подсмеивалась над мужем за его русские привычки, но была так оживлена и весела, как не была во все время жизни на водах. - Лев Толстой, Анна Каренина.

Еще с института, с пятнадцати лет, Лиза постоянно влюблялась во всех привлекательных мужчин и была оживлена́ и счастлива только тогда, когда была влюблена. — Лев Толстой, Крейцерова соната

А за ужином Мелани удивила всех: она нашла в себе силы побороть свою застенчивость и была необычно оживлена́. — Маргарет Митчелл, Унесенные ветром

Эмилия весь этот вечер была очень весела и оживлена́ и выполняла свои обязанности хозяйки с изумительной грацией и благородством, как казалось Доббину. — Уильям Теккерей, Ярмарка тщеславия

Давно не была она так оживленна и разговорчива. - А. А. Фет. Семейство Гольц

Она понимала, что все эти приготовления и суета из-за нее, и была оживленна, и щеки у нее горели. - Г. Я. Бакланов. Мертвые сраму не имут

«Очень некрасива, невзрачна, ― писал Пришвин о Розановой, ― но так оживленна, так игрива в мысли, что становится лучше красивой». - Алексей Варламов. Пришвин или Гений жизни.

Чем по смыслу отличаются слова *оживлена* и *оживлённа*.

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 3):

> оживлённый
>
> кратк. форма прил. -ён, -ен'а (испытывающий оживление: он'а весел'а и
> оживлен'а) и -ён, -ённа (обнаруживающий признаки оживления, выражающий
> оживление: бес'еда оживлённа, 'улицы оживлённы; л'ица гост'ей
> оживлённы)

*Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.*

**P.S.** На мой взгляд, этот словарь даёт точное, исчерпывающее и вполне актуальное различение двух форм краткого прилагательного (совпадающее с первым вариантом по написанию *причастие* - в его "реанимационном" смысле - сюда не относится; в той же словарной статье оно рассмотрено отдельно). Обращает на себя внимание отсутствие формы м. р. "оживлёнен", которую легко сконструировать, даже включив её в списки синонимов (что случается), но которая не прижилась в приличных текстах. Из словарных примеров видно также, что к неодушевлённым сущностям применяется главным образом форма -ённ-, поскольку в таких случаях не подходит значение "испытывать оживление", свойственное форме с -н-.

**Дополнение.** Два значения из более позднего словаря:
*Иллюстрированнный толковый словарь современного русского языка.  Активная, наиболее употребительная лексика русского языка ХХ - начала ХХI века, Владимир Лопатин, Людмила Лопатина, М. 2007*

> ОЖИВЛЁННЫЙ
>
> 1. (-ён, -ена). Испытывающий прилив сил, душевный подъём. *Сегодня она оживлена и возбуждена.*
> 2. (-ён, -ённа). Исполненный жизни, активности, движения, возбуждения. *О. Разговор. Оживлённая торговля. Улицы оживлённы. Оживлённое лицо.*

Comment: Зачем изобретать для конкретного слова свои правила письма и как-то их объяснять. Все примеры в заданном вопросе - это прилагательные, и они должны писаться с двумя НН,  тем не менее почему-то письмо с одним Н  встречается часто.. Вот и надо это исправить, привести слово в общую систему, которая одна и та же для всех причастий и отпричастных прилагательных. Тогда мы получим логику  правописания, которой нам так не хватает. И причем тут форма м.р., мы скажем: мальчик вежлив и воспитан, девочка вежлива и воспитанна, то есть у м.р. свои особенности грамматической формы.

Comment: Кстати, я так и не вижу ответа на вопрос: Чем по смыслу отличаются слова оживлена и оживлённа в приведенных примерах. Я вот могу сказать, что в части выбора Н или НН не отличаются ничем, все они прилагательные и должны писаться с двумя НН. А как и почему в этих конкретных примерах они  должны писаться с вашей точки зрения?

Comment: Язык складывался не из "общих правил" - это правила со своими исключениями из него выводились (а не "изобретались"). Условиться о правилах в написании можно, а подгонять сложившийся в языке традиции словоупотребления  под удобную для запоминания концепцию - дело сомнительное и даже вредное. Ответ на вопрос в словарной статье есть: приписываемое внутреннее состояние, либо его внешнее проявление. Вы предлагаете в интересах единомыслия убить один из двух разных смыслов.

Comment: Я ничего не предлагаю, так как всё уже предложено и выполнено: в правилах ясно написано, что прилагательные должны писаться с двумя НН. А Вы как считаете? Правомерным является их написание с одним Н в приведенных примерах?

Comment: Вспомнил Вашу недавнюю ссылку на _словарное слово по Лопатину_ и добавил статью из более позднего и более "персонального" его словаря. Там тоже разные формы словообразования разнесены по значениям и обе характеризуют состояние, а не случившееся действие "оживления", т. е. оба слова функционируют как кр. прилагательные. В данном случае правило словообразования (не орфографии - затрагивается не только количество букв, а и ударение и произношение е/ё) не подходит под реалии языка - видимо, нужно говорить об исключении.

Comment: У меня два вопроса: 1) На Грамота-ру словарь дает неверную информацию?  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=оживленный&all=x  Там прилагательные с двумя оттенками значений пишутся одинаково с двумя НН. 2) Нам дали 8 примеров (5 примеров с Н, 3 примера с НН). Всё правильно написано, в чём разница между этими предложениями? Я не вижу их анализа.

Answer (score 1):

**Из словаря:** оживлённый; кр. ф. прич. -ён, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ён, -ённа (**испытывающий оживление**: она весела и оживлённа; обнаруживающий признаки оживления, **выражающий оживление**: беседа оживлённа, улицы оживлённы; лица гостей оживлённы).

**Это современное понимание орфографии этих слов**, но еще не принятое и не осознанное всеми авторами, а также нехарактерное для старых текстов.

Частотность в Нацкорпусе 150:16, чаще встречается "она оживлена". Например: ...Светочка была оживлена. [Андрей Битов. Вкус (1960-1999)].

Но ***оживлена*** ― это именно причастие, оно должно иметь **прямое** значение действия "вернуть к жизни", а здесь значение **качественное**  (весела, игрива и т.д).

**Почему так получилось?**  С одной стороны,  это общее правило различения причастий и образованных от них  (переходомв другую часть речи) прилагательных: дети хорошо воспитаны ― она умны и воспитанны. Прямое значение причастия противопоставлено переносному значению прилагательного.

В данном случае скорее дело в том, что переносное значение глагола ***оживить*** закреплено уже в словаре: наполнить жизнью, сделать ярким, сделать активным. **Поэтому считалось, что нет необходимости различать причастие и прилагательное.**

Однако сейчас это, очевидно, **придется делать** в соответствии  с нормами письма.